# When deploying to Azure from git, how do I store my secrets?

Tags: git, security, azure, deployment

I'm setting up a project to deploy to Azure every time a particular branch in github changes. The first step of the deployment is to create the database required by all the other components. In order to do this programmatically, I need to provide credentials.

If I were deploying to Heroku, I would push the credentials to an environmental variable and have the database builder read the credentials from there. What is the analogue in Azure?

Comment: Are you deploying to an Azure Website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are using an Azure website you should be storing your secrets in either App Settings or Connection Strings.  Both of these are available from the configure tab of the web site.

[image: configure tab example]

[image: settings and connection strings]

The connection strings acts just like a connection string in web config.  App settings act like app keys in webconfig apart from it is good practice to access them using the [cloud configuration manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx) and particularly the method [get settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx).